# Being recruited to develop a product that is very similar to my own pet product

Tags: professionalism, recruitment, negotiation, startup

As a recent grad, I spent the summer alongside two others in developing a non-commercial web-app that measures music similarity through the use of AI

It caught the attention of a seed stage start-up who is developing a very, very similar idea. A large component of their app is to measure music taste similarity. They are trying to hire me as a junior data scientist and pay me entry level salary, and be the sole data scientist working on the project. They made it very obvious that they are interested in my experience in developing the web app.

I was then wondering if it would be fair and respectful to bargain a much higher salary (40%+) given that I have existing knowledge that will add direct value to the start-up. How about attempting to sell them the product I have made?

What are your guys thoughts?

Comment: As a matter of course you should always try to negotiate the best salary you can.

Comment: Being fair and respectful has nothing to do with *whether* you try and negotiate, but on how you go about it. So always try (in a fair and respectful way). I'd recommend you read this: https://www.kalzumeus.com/2012/01/23/salary-negotiation/

Comment: Which country Is this? Might affect the results.

Answer (score 4):

> I was then wondering if it would be fair and respectful to bargain a higher salary (20%+) given that I have existing knowledge that will add direct value to the start-up.

There is nothing wrong with trying to negotiate a higher salary, but you might be overestimating the value of your experience.

Let's look at your experience and assume with everything else being equal you spend 2 months full time on your app. If the company would hire someone else, they would need to spend 2 months longer to get up to speed. But since 10 of your months would cost as much of 12 months of another generic candidate, hiring you would make the company worse off after just 1 year (which is less than the typical runway of a startup).

In reality the calculation would be even less in your favour, since I didn't even factor in  time spend on the product on those two extra months or the fact that other candidates will have at least partially relevant experience as well and any candidate who has 2 years of experience as data-scientist in a completely unrelated field would be probably be equally useful to them, if not more.

> How about attempting to sell them the product I have made?

The code you wrote probably isn't worth anything to them. The startup only has time and money to focus on one approach and they already have picked it, working on anything else would be a distraction and not worth the effort unless your app has a very large user base.

Keep in mind that developing a fully fledged marketable product is much more work than just writing a working app.

Finally, your salary will not only be based on what you are worth to the company, but on their budget (which is fairly limited in a start-up), so even if the founders wanted to pay you more, they might not be able to.

Comment: Not sure your assumptions here are quite accurate, the asker's statement that they will be the "sole data scientist" suggest a perhaps fairly large role in the actual functional effort.